# Python - How to remotely execute a script (with some added complexity)

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time designing the following:

I have a client program that receives commands and executes the scripts matching those commands.
This sound simple, but there are a few issues that are best explained in the form of an example:

Take for example an Alarm Clock python script. 
Upon getting the Alarm Clock command (with the time of the alarm etc), the client needs to execute the Alarm Clock script and pass it the settings it received (time of the alarm).

Now imagine after I set the alarm, I want to cancel it. So the client gets a Cancel Alarm command. The client has to disable the Alarm Clock now by sending it a "disable" message.

So basically we need to support:

1. Executing / Starting a script.
2. Interacting with it (like the Cancel command).

The 2nd requirement makes me think that each script should be executed in its own thread. However if that's the case, I'll need to manage the threads somehow so that I'll be able to communicate with them (there is more than 1 script. I.e, alarm, reminder etc).

So what are my options fulfilling these two requirements? 
More specifically:

1. How can I execute a script from inside the `client` script?
2. How do I handle interacting with the other scripts?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html has everything you need.

Comment: So you're saying I should open a subprocess by invoking a `python alarm.py` command and send the data using `communicate`?
I've considered this (I actually implemented this) but it seems like an inelegant solution. 
Also, I'm not entirely sure how I manage all of the `stdins` I get back from the `Popen` call to communicate with the subprocess.

Comment: If you want to have independent scripts, then it's probably the most elegant.  It means a script can die, and it doesn't muck up your server.  When you Popen a new script, it doesn't return a stdin, it returns a Popen object.  Just append it on to a `running_tasks` list.  Or if you want only one instance of a script to ever be runnable, use a `dict`, `{task_name: popen_object}` type of thing.  You can keep track of individual running scripts either using a UUID (or whatever) or looking at the popen object's pid.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've understood your question correctly, or at least part of it. I'm not expert on remote execution, but I'll offer my help where I think I can.

For executing a script from within a script, you can import functions from it.

For example if you define a main function:

```
def main:
    Method1()
    Method2()
```

etc. etc.

Then I believe you can import the script into another script.

```
import script1
```

then you can run main from that script if a certain condition is fulfilled:

```
if condition == true:
    script1.main()
```

You would use input from your remote execution client as your conditions.

I don't know the format of your client but if it had a drop down with different scripts listed you could use:

```
if input == script1:
    script1.main()
elif input == script2:
    script2.main()
```

I think is correct, again, not an expert, but this is how I'd go about it.

Comment: The issue with this is that the client would need an `if` statement for each possible script. Furthermore, it would need to handle some of the logic (like Cancel for the alarm) rather than delegate it to the alarm script.

Comment: That's very true. Apologies for my rather redundant answer in that case. I have very little to none experience in using one script to interact with another whilst it is running.

Comment: It's the thought that counts :)